# Postfix - accept all email to any user at any domain

Tags: postfix, smtp

I need to configure an SMTP server to accept *any* email to any address that might happen to reach it on port 25 and deliver it to a local mailbox (i.e. a spam sinkhole)

The default supported MTA on my O/S is Postfix, of which I have no experience.  I used to do a lot of Sendmail and Exim, but that was years ago.

Can this be done with Postfix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using virtual mailboxes. Instead of the usual lookup maps, you'd have a PCRE table that looks like this:

```
/.*/ spamuser
```

to return the username `spamuser` regardless of what email address is the recipient.

In your postfix.conf you'd have the line

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

There's more information about both [virtual alias maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) and [PCRE tables](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html) at [postfix.org](http://www.postfix.org)

Comment: thanks - seems to work fine!  I expected that a PCRE map would do it, but the hint I needed was using `pcre:` for the map file.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I done it

create user webmail

```
adduser webmail
```

I had to install the postfix-pcre package.
Code:

```
 sudo apt-get install postfix-pcre
```

I created a file called /etc/postfix/virtual as follows:-

Code:

```
/.*/                        webmail
```

edited `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to add this line:

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

For the absolute newbies (like me), if the configuration is correct, the query command:
Code:

```
postmap -q test@a pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

would return the email id specified in virtual file (/etc/postfix/virtual). In this case.
Code:

```
webmail
```

To test the working, use the mail command from the terminal.
Code:

```
mail testmail@example.com
```

enter the subject, mail body and press Ctrl+D (to exit the compose window).

To view the message use the following command. (webmail is the mail id configured in virtual file. Substitute with your name.)
Code:

```
mail webmail
```

PS:To check the mail log use the following command.
Code:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make postfix into an open proxy that will accept mail for any domain, you may want to look into this piece of code: http://www.postfix.org/smtp-sink.1.html

It's basically a load tester (accept then discard), but you can also configure it to accept then store.

Comment: I need it to catch _all_ domains, not be configured with a list.

Comment: Well, that sort of counters the way postfix was designed, and the way mail works (domains need to be configured in postfix, and have an MX record pointing to it), unless you want to create an open relay that doesn't actually forward. Which is possible, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, an open relay that doesn't relay (and then redirects to a local mailbox) would achieve what I need.